# Enable the unicode typing mode to my project to the users in java web application

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, unicode

I want to enable the typing mode to Tamil by checking an check box. That is, I want code in java or javascript to enable the Tamil mode like Tamil Wikipedia. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: For us who don't know how Tamil Wikipedia works, could you describe this?

Comment: @Paŭlo Ebermann:  There would be checkbox near each textbox which says 'Type in Tamil'. On checking it, when you type in the textbox, tamil is input instead of english.  This feature exists on many indian language wikipedias.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a javascript function to work on keypress of textarea/textinput and transliterate whatever is being input to tamil based on a mapping.

I have written a very similar jquery plugin but for Malayalam.  Change the mappings to Tamil and you should be done.

Feel free to modify, use and share: http://github.com/nishan/jquery-swanalekha

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have achieved. Thank you very much.